# The below Bash Shell script is used to check the mount points on the server but it is cutting the correct output., .Can someone please guide?

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
df -k ${MP} &>/dev/null &

DFPID=$!
for (( i=1 ; i<$TIME_TILL_STALE ; i++ )) ; do
    if ps -p $DFPID > /dev/null ; then
        sleep 1
    else
        break
    fi
done
if ps -p $DFPID > /dev/null ; then
    $(kill -s SIGTERM $DFPID &>/dev/null)
    ERR_MESG[${#ERR_MESG[*]}]="${MP} did not respond in $TIME_TILL_STALE sec. Seems to be stale." '
```

Error message is `CRITICAL: /MOUNTS/DBAuftraege did not respond in 3 sec. Seems to be stale.`
Error  line is  `df -k ${MP} >&/dev/null`

According to my boss here important thing is not recognizable. Can someone please guide?

Comment: What is the output of `df -k ${MP}`? Remove `&>/dev/null` and add the output to your question.

Comment: The correct code is here  https://github.com/echocat/nagios-plugin-check_mountpoints/blob/master/check_mountpoints.sh  but this code has variable ${DFARGS} In front of df -k ...what does this signify and what is it doing I am not unable to figure out...